# xsd doesn't see xs:decimal type

Tags: xml, types, xsd, decimal, restriction

Hi I've changed my element type from xs:integer to xs:decimal, but when i try to validate my xml an error occurred: " **'0.2' is not a valid value for 'integer'.**"
I don't understand why the result type is integer yet.
This is my xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xs:schema xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com" 
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com">

 <xs:element name="distribution">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="value" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>   

<xs:element name = "type">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="value">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

And the xml I want to validate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<working xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="processoproduttivo.xsd">

<resources> <!-- resources map-->
    <resource resourcename="A1">
        <resourcenumber>4</resourcenumber><!-- number of machines-->
        <capacity>50</capacity><!-- machine's capacity-->
        <distribution><!-- type of distribution-->
            <type>Uniform</type>
            <value>0.2</value>
            <value>4</value>
        </distribution>
    </resource>
</resources>
</working>
```

Comment: How do you do the validation?

Comment: I use Notepad++ and https://www.corefiling.com/opensource/schemavalidate/.

Comment: You should consider to use XmlSpy or Oxigen for editing and validating this sort of things. I think the most possible reason is that on the server uses a locale where a decimal number is serialized differently, e.g. 0,2 is a valid decimal for some locales, and of course these locales find 0.2 invalid. I saw similar problems in Java (however there xs:decimal would be mapped to  
java.math.BigDecimal, not Integer - and of course, the server is right, 0.2 is not an Integer :) )

Comment: btw, you can simplify your value def in this way: <xs:element name="value" type="xs:decimal"/>

Comment: Another way of validating XMLs against XSDs in [Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436183/using-notepad-to-validate-xml-against-an-xsd), maybe it will do a better job.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are validating this document against this schema.

For a start, the namespaces don't match. Your schema is for namespace "https://www.w3schools.com" (which is bad practice, because I don't think you own that domain), but your instance appears to be in no namespace.

== UPDATE ==

You have now edited the question to show the full XML. This shows that the XML instance is indeed in the target namespace of the schema. However, it contains an `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute which is only useful for validating no-namespace elements, and isn't going to help in finding schema declarations for an element in the "https://www.w3schools.com" namespace.

Comment: Hi I edit the first line of my xml. I don't know if you refer to its. Could you be more clear?

Comment: So, how can I fix it?

Comment: There are so many possible ways of finding a schema to use for validating a source document, and I have no idea what environment you are in or what your constraints are, so I can't advise you.